# With MS team build, can I automatically compare the current build with the last build?

Tags: c#, tfs, compare, diff, tfsbuild

We are using TFS/team build to produce builds for our C# web application.

I want every new build produced to be diff'd/compared against the last build.  I want a .txt file (or something) to be produced after each build that shows me all of the files that are new or different from the previous build.  Obviously, I could do this manually using something like "beyond compare", but I want to bake this right into my Team build .xaml process.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TFS already associates changesets with a build. Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

[Writing the Build Report with Associated Changesets and Work Items to a file as part of the build](http://blogs.msmvps.com/vstsblog/2014/05/19/writing-the-build-report-with-associated-changesets-and-work-items-to-a-file-as-part-of-the-build/)